# I bricked my apt on Raspbian

Tags: apt, raspbian

I was attempting to update my npm on a Raspbian Buster installation. The version provided by the package manager was not sufficient.

First I followed some of the suggestions in [this thread](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1877) and then tried upgrading to Bullseye using [these instructions](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/upgrade-raspberry-pi-os-to-bullseye-from-buster).

I'm not entirely sure if this started before or after attempting to upgrade to Bullseye, but now whenever I run `sudo apt install <anything>` it tells me that it cannot install any of the dependencies. When I try to reinstall an already installed package I get the error that it cannot download the package. Here are two examples:

```
% sudo apt install nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs : Depends: libnode72 (= 12.22.12~dfsg-1~deb11u4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

```
% sudo apt reinstall vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of vim is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

The system is fully updated and upgraded (as far as I can tell):

```
% sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade
Hit:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

No packages appear to be on hold:

```
% sudo apt-mark showhold
%
```

I tried various fixes suggested on the internet:

```
% sudo apt --fix-broken install
%
```

and

```
% sudo dpkg --configure -a
%
```

No results.
I also renamed some *.list files to *.list.bak in /etc/apt/sources.list.d, but I believe I did that only after the issue started in an attempt to resolve it.

How do I recover my package manager to make it useable again?

**Edits:**

Output of `apt policy nodejs`

```
% sudo apt policy nodejs
nodejs:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 12.22.12~dfsg-1~deb11u4
  Version table:
     12.22.12~dfsg-1~deb11u4 50
         50 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf Packages
```

Contents of /etc/apt/sources.list

```
% cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ bullseye main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

Output of `uname -m`

```
% uname -m                                                                                                                                                                                                              
armv7l
```

Output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
% lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

Noteworthy: it still lists as buster, not bullseye.

**Progress Edit:**
So, I mentioned above that I followed [these instructions](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1877) to try to upgrade my npm. I believe this to have added an entry in sources.list.d, which I had disabled again. Enabling this entry again allowed me to run `apt install nodejs`. I tried installing some other packages, e.g. `sudo apt install cowsay` which succeeded. I then proceeded to try to run reinstall for those new packages `sudo apt reinstall cowsay` which also succeeded. Trying to reinstall packages that had been installed before continued to fail with a message that the package cannot be downloaded. When I manually uninstall and reinstall the package however, it succeeded: `sudo apt remove nano && sudo apt install nano`. Reinstalling after a manual uninstall and install succeeds now: `sudo apt reinstall nano`.

However, trying to install other packages continues to fail. E.g. installing npm fails with a long list of `node-*` dependencies (including nodejs which I just manually installed). Also, trying to install e.g. aptitude (which was recommended in some sources as being potentially able to recover a borked apt system) fails:

```
% sudo apt install aptitude
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 1.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 9) but 8.3.0-6+rpi1 is to be installed
            Depends: libxapian30 (>= 1.4.17~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So while there was some progress (being able to install nodejs) it seams I'm still not out of the woodwork.

Comment: please add the output of `apt policy nodejs` to your question.

Comment: Hi Daniel, nice having you here, and welcome to the community. You said you modified `/etc/apt/sources.list`; my best bet is that there's a subtle typo in there or something. Please edit your question to contain the contents of that file :)

Comment: Thank you! I provided the both in the edits above.

Comment: Raspbian 32bit or 64bit ?

Answer (score 0):

[What is up with the different repositories and URLs?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/137601/145061)

> Presumably you have installed Raspberry Pi OS 64bit on the newer Pi.
> This uses the standard Debian ARM64 repository not the Raspbian. The
> firmware is still provided by Raspberry Pi Ltd. and the source is the
> same for 32/64 bit

Try this:

`deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ bullseye main`

Check this to:

[Upgrading your Raspberry Pi to Bullseye](https://www.sanderh.dev/upgrade-Raspberry-Pi-bullseye/)

[Raspbian 32bit vs 64bit - very different apt sources.list](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=333288)

[Raspberry PI OS/Debian 11 Bullseye APT Repos](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/blog/craigevil-176422/raspberry-pi-os-debian-11-bullseye-apt-repos-38636/)

Or try this:

**`/etc/apt/sources.list`**

`deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ bullseye main contrib non-free rpi`

**`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list`**

`deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ bullseye main`

Update:

`apt-get update`

`apt-get dist-upgrade`

Clean & remove:

`apt-get autoremove`

`apt-get autoclean`

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

0. Make a backup of `/etc/apt/` and `/var/lib/apt/lists/`
1. Delete or move your modifief list entries

`mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MY_FILES.list /BACKUP/`

2. Remove the existing package lists and clean the package cache

`rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

`apt clean`

3. Restore your original `sources.list` from a backup or create one with the default `sources.list`

`cp /usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list`

4. Update

`apt update`

5. Reinstall base package

`apt --reinstall install raspberrypi-sys-mods raspberrypi-kernel raspberrypi-bootloader`

**If you have made extensive changes to your system it might be necessary to reinstalling your operating system.**

Comment: Check what and if that works for you and then edit the answer post pls^^

Comment: I'm not sure I fully follow the first part of your post (up to "Or try this"). I followed the links but wasn't really sure what I am looking for. 
I did try the changes listed below, but to the same results as stated before.

Comment: Ok so both deb sources don't work archive and mirrordirector ?

Comment: Have you check the descriptions in  the links?

Comment: From one post | Repeat the same steps for any other .list files located in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory. | https://www.sanderh.dev/upgrade-Raspberry-Pi-bullseye/

Comment: There is a difference between in `uname -u` and in `apt policy nodejs` `armv7l` vs `armhf` in your post | I don't know if that fits

Comment: Yes, I put the archive URL by itself in sources.list with all additional *.list in sources.list.d disabled and then enabled the raspi.list one including the archive URL and put the mirrordirector URL in sources.list, but running `sudo apt install nodejs` still failed.

Comment: > Have you check the descriptions in the links?
Yes, I've looked at the links and read through them. They seem to be instructions on how to upgrade to bullseye and/or listing various package source lists. I'm not really sure what I am looking for or how to apply that to my situation. I followed upgrade instructions (which I linked above) very similar to the one you've linked.

Comment: Can you try `apt install -f nodejs` or `apt install nodejs=12.22.12~dfsg-1~deb11u4`

Comment: > From one post | Repeat the same steps for any other .list files located in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory.
I've done that. I've also tried disabling other entries in sources.list.d to no success.

Comment: > There is a difference between in uname -u and in apt policy nodejs armv7l vs armhf in your post | I don't know if that fits
I'm afraid I can't tell if that fits or not. I'm really absolutely unfamiliar with the details of any of this and just following the instructions given.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146443/discussion-between-blockchain-office-and-daniel-baulig).